# How do I get my jQuery Validator Code to run a second time after a form has already been submitted?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Here is the scenario.

A user fills out a form. He forgets some required info. My validation code indicates to the user the missing field is required. He fills out the form fully and submits. Presto it works.

Now, the user manually deletes the required field and hits submit again. Presto it works (IT SHOUDLNT). How can I get my validation to work a second time around to prevent empty fields from being submitted? Here is my code. It only works on 1 iteration of a form submit. All subsequent submits ignore my validation.

Thank you...

```
//Validation  
$('#CommentsForm').validate({
    rules: {
        Author: "required",
        Message: "required"
    },
    messages: {
        Author: "Author is required.",
        Message: "Comment is required."
    },
    errorContainer: "#CommentsErrorBox",
    errorLabelContainer: "#CommentsErrorBox ul",
    wrapper: "li"
});

//User Clicked Submit Button
$('#CommentsForm').live('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //Prevent Browser from getting new url

    //Create JSON object
    var jsonCommentData = {
        ID: $('#HiddenID').val(),
        Author: $('#Author').val(),
        Message: $('#Message').val()
    }

    //Add the comment.
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/_CommentsAdd',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(jsonCommentData),
        dataType: 'html',
        contentType: 'application/json',

        //The request was a success. Repopulate the div with new result set.
        success: function (data) {
            $('#AjaxComments').html(data);
            $('abbr.timeago').timeago(); //update the timestamp with timeago

            //Change colors of message.                
            if ($('#CommentStatus').html() == "Your Comment Has Been Added!") {
                $('#CommentStatus').css('color', 'GREEN');
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert('Fail');
        }
    });
});
```

Here is my Partial view: _Comments

```
@model DH.ViewModels.CommentsViewModel

<div id="AjaxComments">
@{
    <input type="hidden" id="HiddenPageNumber" value="@Model.PageNumber.ToString()" />
    <input type="hidden" id="HiddenPageCount" value="@Model.PageCount.ToString()" />

    //No Comments Yet
    if (Model.CommentStatus.Length > 0)
    {
            <div id="CommentStatus">@Model.CommentStatus</div>
    }

    foreach (var item in Model.Comment)
    {   
        <div class="CommentContainer">
            <div class="RateComment">
                <img src="/content/images/icons/Thumbs-Up-16x16.png" alt="Thumbs Up" title="Uprate Comment" style="margin-top: 10px;" />
                <div class="CommentRating">8</div>
                <img src="/content/images/icons/Thumbs-Down-16x16.png" alt="Thumbs Down" title="Downrate Comment" style="margin-top: 5px;" />
            </div>
            <div class="CommentHeader">
                <div class="CommentAuthor">@item.Author</div>
                <div class="MessageDate">
                    <img src="/content/images/icons/Clock-16x16.png" width="16" height="16" alt="Comment Time" style="vertical-align: middle; padding-bottom: 2px;" />
                    <abbr class="timeago" title="@item.MessageDate" style="border-bottom-width: 0;">@item.MessageDate</abbr>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="CommentMessage">@item.Message</div>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>
    }
}

<div id="Pagination">
@{ 
    //Setting up Increments of 10 Pagination links
    int StartPage;
    int EndPage;
    int PageNumber = Model.PageNumber;
    int PageCount = Model.PageCount;

    if (PageCount < 10) {
        StartPage = 1;
        EndPage = PageCount;
    }
    else {
        if (PageNumber < 10) {
            StartPage = 1;
            EndPage = 10;
        }
        else {
            StartPage = PageNumber - 5;
            EndPage = PageNumber + 4;
            if (EndPage > PageCount) {
                EndPage = PageCount;
                StartPage = EndPage - 9;
            }
        }
    }

    //Display "Page of" if there are comments.
    if (@Model.PageCount > 0)
    {
        <div id="PageOf">Page @Model.PageNumber of @Model.PageCount</div>
    }

    //Set up First and Prev arrow links
    if (Model.PageNumber > 1) {
        <a class="PaginationLink" title="Prev" href="">< Prev</a>
    }

    //Loop through and create the page #'s.
    for (var PageCounter = StartPage; PageCounter <= EndPage; PageCounter++) {
        //Display the Page # in a Black Box
        if (PageCounter == PageNumber) {
            <span class="CurrentPage">@PageNumber</span>
        }
        //Create the Page # Links.
        else {
            <a class="PaginationLink" title="@PageCounter" href="">@PageCounter</a>
        }
    }

    //Set up Next and Last arrow links
    if (Model.PageNumber < Model.PageCount) {
        <a class="PaginationLink" title="Next" href="">Next ></a>
    }
} 
</div>

<div id="CommentsFormContainer">
    <form id="CommentsForm" action="">
    <div id="CommentsErrorBox"><ul></ul></div>
    <fieldset id="CommentsFormFieldset">
        <legend id="CommentsFormLegend" align="center">Add a Comment</legend>
        <label for="Author" class="LabelAuthorMessage">Author:&nbsp;</label><input type="text" id="Author" name="Author" size="30" class="CommentInputs" />
        <label for="Message" class="LabelAuthorMessage">Comment:&nbsp;</label><textarea id="Message" name="Message" cols="35" rows="5" class="CommentInputs"></textarea>
        <input type="text" id="CharCount" value="0" readonly="readonly" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <label for="CharCount" id="LabelCharCount">* Max 200 Characters</label>
        <input type="submit" id="SubmitComment" value="Submit" name="SubmitComment" style="float: left; margin-left: 50px;" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: One problem is that you've wrapped your `.validate()` within a submit handler.  The validation plugin already has that built-in and does not need to be inside a submit handler function.

Comment: @Sparky672 has a good point. I'd like to add you should use the .valid() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is totally with your implementation.

The following occurs when the page loads which makes your form work sucessfully on the first submit...

```
var validator = form.validate({
    rules: {
        Author: "required",

        etc....
```

Then, because you've enclosed it again within a submit handler, it's reinitialized here...

```
form.live('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //Prevent Browser from getting new url

    $(this).validate();
```

... which breaks it for the next submit.

All you need to do is initialize it **once** (including all the options) and **not** inside a submit handler...

```
$('#CommentsForm').validate({
    rules: {
        Author: "required",

        etc....
```

Refer to the source code of [these official demos](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/).

---

**EDIT:**

Again, you do not need a submit handler as it's interfering with your form submission.

In other words, your validation is working fine but when you hit "submit", your external submit handler function takes over completely so it's no wonder that validation then starts failing.

As I mentioned in my original comments, the Validation plugin has a submit handler built in to handle everything including your ajax.

Remove all this completely...

```
form.live('submit', function (e) { ....
```

Then *inside* your `validate()` function, you'd simply add a submit handler [as per the plugin documentation listed as the second option](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions)...

```
$('#CommentsForm').validate({
    rules: {
        Author: "required",

        /// etc....

    },

    submitHandler: function(form) {

        /// put all your ajax and such in here

    }

 });
```

Comment: I updated the code to reflect your changes but im still getting the same result. It looks like it might have to do with the fact that after the ajax post my controller is returning: return PartialView("_comments", Model); Once the partial view is reloaded, i seem to lose validation abilities.

Comment: Im getting close. So, all of my jquery is located in a seperate .js file called from my _layout page. I decided to take the jquery functions from this script and put them in the partial view instead. IT WORKED. However, I would prefer to keep all my jquery in a seperate file. How can I reinitialize that validator after a partial view is returned? That would solve my problem.

Comment: @Maddhacker24, Please edit your question by _appending_ to it. The way you've edited it, you've totally disconnected all meaning from my answer.

Comment: @Maddhacker24, You've kept your submit handler function despite what is shown in [the working demos and examples](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/). Again, it's superfluous and likely the root cause of all this. Anything you'd want to attach to the submit handler would also go inside the `validate()` function using the _built-in_ `submitHandler`. See my edit.

Comment: Sorry about that. I misunderstood. I removed the form.live block and added the submit handler into the validate block. Im still having the same issue once the partialview is reloaded. Once the partialview has been reloaded, the validate code block is not acccessible unless I remove it from the external file and put the code into the partial view page. Just wish I could figure out how to have the code block inside of my external js file run once the partialview has been reloaded.

Comment: For now I guess i will just have to run with using the validate code inside of my partialview page. Thanks for your help.