# jquery.form/validate plugin only allow submit if input is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-forms-plugin

I'd like to use the jQuery.Form/Validate plugins to only allow my form to be submitted if any of inputs were actually changed.

There is callback logic for this using `beforeSubmit:` : http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object. However, I can't seem to make it work.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'input[type="submit"]', function(){
 var $form =$('form');

$form.validate({
  submitHandler: function($form) {
   $($form).ajaxSubmit({
  beforeSubmit: function(arr, $form){           
      var value = '', storedValue='';
      $($form+':input').each(function (index, el) {
  value=$(el).val();
  storedValue=$(el).data("stored");            
      if(value!=storedValue){
      console.log("Changed");   return true;
  } 
      else {
      return false; console.log("NOT changed");
  }
});   

...success handling, etc..

beforeSubmit: function(arr, $form) { 
  var value = '', storedValue='';
  $($form+':input').each(function (index, this) {
    value=this.value;
    storedValue=$(this).data("stored");            
        if(value!=storedValue){
          console.log("Changed");return true;
        } 
        else {
         return false; console.log("NOT changed");
        }
  });                   
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<form id="myForm">
  <input data-stored="my title" value="my title"/>
  <textarea data-stored="my description">my description</textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="submit/>
</form>
```

Currently the console.log shows, `"Changed"` regardless of whether the `storedValue` is equal or not to the input.

Comment: I deleted my comment because I thought you were using a different plugin.  In either case, my comment was valid for the [Bassistance Validation plugin](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/) (as per your tag) and _might_ be valid for others.

Comment: @thanks I'll check to see whether including the `submitHandler:` code inside the `validate({...` function is necessary or not. Either way thanks for the tip!

Comment: It's not necessarily my point that you'd need the `submitHandler`... it's that you should not enclose `.validate()` within a handler.  Because `.validate()` initializes the form validation on page load.  But when it's inside a handler, the validation options are only initialized when that event handler is fired, which leads to weird & unexpected results.

Comment: @Sparky672, the `submitHandler:` enclosing the `validate()` is necessary for my example. Should I refactor it in another way?

Comment: That's fine if you need to use it _inside of `validate()`_.  But enclosing `validate()` within a handler causes validation to be initialized improperly. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609567/how-do-i-get-my-jquery-validator-code-to-run-a-second-time-after-a-form-has-alre/10609871#10609871), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609567/how-do-i-get-my-jquery-validator-code-to-run-a-second-time-after-a-form-has-alre/10609871#10609871), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825290/jquery-validation-validate-several-time-a-field-in-a-hidden-area/10825498#10825498).

Comment: Yes, think of it just like any other jQuery plugin.  Typically, you just initialize the plugin and its options within a `ready` event.  You rarely see the initialization jQuery plugins enclosed within a handler.  Treat the initialization of the `.validate()` plugin the same way.  That's why it has a built-in `submitHandler` event.

Comment: @Sparky672 ok, now I see  my confusion. How do you capture stuff from a click event if it is preferred to initialize the `validate()` on page load rather than inside the `on() click` function? I wrapped the validate inside the click event because often I have **many** forms on the page and need to capture data depending on what the user selects (like exposing a specific input form `on() click`. Thoughts?

Comment: @sparky672, said another way how do I pass custom data from a click event into the `validate()` function?

Comment: "running" validation and initializing it are two different things.  Personally, I would initialize it on all page forms; then it "runs" only when the visitor uses a particular form.

Comment: Also, focus on those three SO questions/answers I posted.  There are various external links to examples, documentation, etc. contained within those that should be helpful.

Comment: I think my question is simple, i just need to pass data into the validate function for use in the `success:` handler, etc. Is there a reference for that?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by _"pass data into the validate function"_.  The `validate` function looks at the form and its input data whenever the user hits the submit button.  Since I'm not entirely clear on your specific question and this is not the place for extended discussion, I'd encourage you to post a new question about this particular aspect.

Comment: @Sparky672 ok i'll do that now and reference this SO Q&A.

Comment: Nothing wrong with linking to this question, but try to make your new question as "self-contained" as possible so that it doesn't _require_ looking at this one.  Also make sure that it's different enough to not get closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @Sparky672 ok here is that new question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986523/jquery-validate-plugin-on-multiple-dynamically-added-forms. I'd appreciate your thoughts if you'd have the time. Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it will never show "Not Changed" since it `returns false` before it hits that part.  You should filter out the submit button too since you probably aren't checking its value.

```
$($form+':input').not(':submit').each(function(index, this) {
    value = this.value;
    storedValue = $(this).data("stored");
    if (value != storedValue) {
        console.log("Changed");
        return true;      
    }
    else {       
        console.log("NOT changed");
        return false;
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**
With great assistance from @wirey, together we've (@timrpeterson and @wirey) put together a solution. Instead of returning true/false within the `each()` loop, I incremented a value  ,`totalChanged`, and assessed after the `each()` loop whether or not it was greater than 0.

here's the code:

```
beforeSubmit: function(arr, $form){   
var value = '', storedValue='', totalChanged=0;
$('#myForm :input').not(':submit,:hidden').each(function (i, el) {
  //console.log($(this));
    console.log($($form));
    value=$(el).val(); 
    storedValue=$(el).data("stored");          
    if (value != storedValue) {  
      totalChanged++;    
    }
    else {     
    }
}); //each

  if(totalChanged>0){
     console.log("at least one changed");
     return true;
  }
  else{
     console.log("All NOT changed");
     return false;
  }
} //beforeSubmit
```

Comment: -@wirey, thanks i think there is still a problem with my `each()` loop as the first value, the `title` is "NOT changed" but then the `description` and `submit` inputs are "changed". Probably you can't `return true/false` within the loop? thoughts?

Comment: it's also weird that there are still 3 console.logs even though the `:submit` was filtered out. Again, the `each()` loop seems problematic.

Comment: @timpeterson just saw that also.  It seems it automatically generates a hidden field with value submit also.  Also it looks like if you return false it stops executing so if the textarea changes and not the title, it will never reach the textarea validation.  Are you returning false to stop the form from submitting?  Here's an update fiddle of it working like you want I think.  http://jsfiddle.net/nELVQ/6/  Except in this fiddle there's no return false

Comment: -@wirey, awesome, thanks. That is doing it. One last question if you don't mind. I of course have multiple forms on my real page and console.log($(this)) shows that these inputs which aren't part of the `id=myForm` are being evaluated too. I'm a little confused because `console.log($($form))` is only evaluating `id=myForm`. There has to be some way to restrict this `each()` loop but i'm not sure, thoughts?

Comment: So it's evaluating elements from different forms on the page also?  I'm not too sure since `$($form+':input')` should probably be filtering only elements from the current form I think.  Else you can select the right form by hardcoding `$(#myForm :input).not().each()`

Comment: -@wirey, yeah that's what i did (see your updated answer above), i have many forms using the validate plugin and think `$form` is being assigned to each of them. Thanks for all your help. I'm all set now!