# Initialize jQuery validate() function on multiple dynamically added forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-forms-plugin

It is has been suggested that it is best to initialize a `$('#form').validate({})` function on page load rather than on a click event: [jquery.form/validate plugin only allow submit if input is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984196/jquery-form-validate-plugin-only-allow-submit-if-input-is-changed)

I'm wondering how to do this for multiple dynamically added forms without wrapping the `$('#form').validate({})` function inside of a `on('click', 'input[type="submit"]',` function.

Take this code for example:

```
var id="some identifier for the specific form that is submitted";
`$('#form'+id).validate({})`
```

1. How does this unique identifier, `id`, which is required to distinguish each form get created in the first place?
2. And what if you don't know the `id` after the page is loaded because it has been created dynamically, e.g., by AJAX.

I have been doing this but this is is what's **not** recommended:

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'input[type="submit"]', function(){
  var id=this.id;
  $('#form'+id).validate({});
});
```

thoughts?

thanks,
tim

Comment: @Sparky672 Yes, I'm making a commenting system. Each comment can be commented on but I don't know the `comment_id` for the next form until I insert the comment into the database and return its row `id`.  I guess you are right though I could initialize `validate()` on the new form after my `templating()` function generates it.

Comment: The form does not exist at all when the page loads? If so, then instead of initializing the `validate()` on `submit`, I'd initialize it immediately after the form is created (`$(#myNewform).validate({ options, etc. })`)

Comment: Yes, you'd want it initialized _before_ submitting it, not after/during.

Comment: The general reasoning is that i'm playing with fire in the call stack by initializing during submitting? Also, For the forms that exist on page load should I initialize each of them with this: `$('form').each(function(){...$(this).validate()});`?

Comment: Yes, if all `validate()` options/instances are the same for all the existing forms, I don't see why you couldn't initialize them all with an `.each(function(){`.

Comment: yes, the options will be the same. To make sure, I can add a class to the selector like this: `$('.someform').each(function()...`?

Comment: You might not be playing with fire, but like I showed in those other three questions, you'll get weird problems when the forms don't validate and you try to submit them a second time.

Comment: i see, thanks for all the clarifications. I'll look over those links more carefully now and upvote your answers. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I appreciate it but let me post an answer below instead.

Comment: @Sparky672 ok, that will work too, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the form does not exist at all when the page loads, then instead of initializing the `.validate()` on submit, I'd initialize it immediately after the form is created...

```
// code that dynamically creates #myNewform, then initialize validate()

$('#myNewform').validate();
```

(`validate()` should not be inside a submit handler because the validation is not initialized until after the submit button is clicked.  This leads to issues when the form fails validation and must be submitted a second time.  The second submit then re-initializes the plugin on the form a second time.  See  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609567/how-do-i-get-my-jquery-validator-code-to-run-a-second-time-after-a-form-has-alre/10609871#10609871), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609567/how-do-i-get-my-jquery-validator-code-to-run-a-second-time-after-a-form-has-alre/10609871#10609871), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825290/jquery-validation-validate-several-time-a-field-in-a-hidden-area/10825498#10825498) for similar issues.)

For existing `form` on page...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myform').validate();
});
```

or for multiple `form`'s sharing same validation options...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ('.myform').each(function(){
        $(this).validate();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a function to handle validation that you can call once your dynamically added form is inserted.

```
function initializeValidation(form) {
    $(form).validate({
      ...
    })
  }
```

Once your ajax is completed successfully you call this function.

```
$.ajax({
    success: function(response) {
        $('#form-container').append(response);
        initializeValidation($('#form-container').find('form').last());
    }
});
```